# How to merge multiple arrays that are depending on a function in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, merge, array-merge

I am seeking for someone's knowledge out here.

Right now, I would need to merge several arrays into a bigger one, but all of those arrays depend on a function.

This function returns a numeric array containing different quantities of numbers between 1 and 7 :

```
function Possible($i, $j, $grid)
$possible = Possible($i, $j, $grid)
```

I'm working with a grid, and the function returns a different array for every case of the grid. What I would like to do is to merge those 7 arrays into another one. Some numbers may be present more than once in this big array, but I want it this way.

I tried using for loops, while loops and some other techniques, but nothing worked. In this case, it is not possible to manually define every array, since they change depending of what is contained in the grid and there are too many. It has to be done automatically, and this is where I get stuck.

```
for ($jj=0; $j<7; $j++){
    $possRow = array_merge( ###what do I add here or what do I change in this code to make everything work###
```

Thank you if someone can help me out!

Etpi

Comment: Please post an example of the **array contents** and an example of what you would like the result to be. Your description of the situation isn't terrifically clear.

Answer (score 1):

hope this help:

```
  $biggerOneArray = array();
    for($k=0;$k<7;$k++) {
     $biggerOneArray[] = Possible($i,$j,$grid);
}
```

Then you can check your bigger array, may contains all arrays of the iterations of the loop (7 arrays merged).

```
var_dump($biggerOneArray);
```

The output should be this:

```
array(
      (int) 0 => array(
           'key' => 'value',
           'key2' => 'value2'
           ),
      (int) 1 => array(
           'key3' => 'value3',
           'key4' => 'value4'
            )
)
```

etc...

Comment: var_dump($biggerOneArray);

This returns a lot of messages : 
`array
  empty`
It seems no values are added to the $biggerOneArray .

Comment: Then you should check if your function "Possible" is returning an array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but your description isn't very clear. But just to get you started you might look at this solution.

```
function Possible($i, $j, $grid) {
    // some code ... e.g. $array[] = "some data";

    return $array;
}
```

By creating a small array for each grid and returning it using `return $array` you get a few little arrays which you can inturn place into a `for` loop to merge it into one larger array. However i believe the var `$jj` must have some meaning in the function it self as well.

```
for($jj=0;$jj<7;$jj++) {
    $merged_array[$jj] = Possible($i,$j,$grid);
}
```

Maybe if you descripe your problem a little more and post an exmple of the array's your working with i can give you a better answer.

Comment: yeah sorry about the jj variables, they're supposed to be simply "j". Just edited that. [writing more information currently]

Comment: Yeah sorry about the jj variables, they're supposed to be simply "j". Just edited that. 

I thought it might have been a bit hard to understand.

Here's the function.

>`function Possible($i, $j, $grid){ 
$Row = PossibleRow($i, $grid);
$Column = PossibleColumn($j, $grid);

$inter2 = array_intersect($Row, $Column);

return $inter2;`

Example of an array I'm working with :
The function Possible(3, 4, $grid) returns an array like this (1, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: It contains numbers from 1 to 7, between 1 and 7 numbers per case's array.
I'm trying to store every value of the numbers in every case of a row of the grid in one bigger array, which would be like : 
(1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7)